# Rails 4, add dynamic fields without nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I'm currently sitting with a problem where I am trying to add dynamic fields, and it works, however I need to created a second model for the nested attributes that are dynamically generated on the field.

I have a very easy and simple form which asks for a user's name, I want to be able to allow the user to click a button ("Add additional name") and have that field added dynamically then add another name. Can I do this using only the one model and controller, and without using nested forms?

This is what I currently have, but I do not want it working this way:

**Controller**

```
class GuestsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  def index
    @guest = Guest.all
  end

  def new
    guest = Guest.new
    @guest_form = GuestForm.new(guest)
  end

  def show
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    guest = Guest.new
    @guest_form = GuestForm.new(guest)
    @guest_form.submit(guest_params)

    if @guest_form.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Thank you for replying' }
        format.js
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
    @guest.destroy
    redirect_to guests_path
  end

private

  def guest_params
    params.require(:guest).permit(:status, :name, :message, plusones_attributes: [:id, :name, :oldness, :_destroy])
  end

end
```

**Models:**

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plusones, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end

class Plusone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest
end
```

So ideally I would like to use one Model, and allow additional fields to be entered of the exact same attribute, meaning if I have a Name: field, I should be able to click "Add another name" and add that name, and that would be saved as an individual guest in the table, meaning the first guest would have guest_id of 1, and the dynamically added field for another guest would add a guest with guest_id of 2.

Comment: What you have tried? Plz, post your related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that allowed me to keep my nested attributes and still be able to display the related child elements in the index page.

This is what I did to get the plusones related to the guest_id to display within index.html.erb

```
<% @guest.each do |guest| %>
  <% guest.plusones.each do |plus| %>
    <%= plus.name %>
    <%= plus.oldness %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a mistake in thinking that there must be a one to one relationship between controllers and models. Have a look at [ActiveRecord's Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). That shows that you can have a single form submit data to an object and it's sub-objects in one action.

Have a look at [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), for information about how to configure a form to allow you to enter data for sub-objects.

When I've worked with nested set, I've found using a JavaScript tool like [dynatree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/index.html) is the best way to display the nested data to users. I've also created a gem [TreeDecorator](https://github.com/reggieb/TreeDecorator), to make it easy to render nested sets as nested HTML lists, that can then be passed to dynatree.

Comment: ReggieB, I am using nested forms and attributes using ActionForm. I need to display the Guest and their Plusone (additional guest), so the Plusones are displayed in relation to the guest_id. So www.domain.com/guests/1 would show the Guest and Plusones for Guest with an id of 1, however I need this to show in a table on the index method (page) for all the guests and their relational plusones. @Musad

Comment: Then I think you want to use JavaScript to dynamically pull the show (and other actions) into the index view. If it was me, I'd use AngularJS to add the functionality in the front end, and use rails to handle the AJAX calls at the backend.

Comment: So there no way of using a single controller and just add an additional field without using nested fields, I want the user to enter a name, then dynamically add a field to add another name?